# Play Store Open button links to which of my Activities

Tags: android, google-play

Suppose I have an Android app that contains more than one launchable Activity (so marked with the LAUNCHER category. If a user downloads my app from the Play Store, they will of course see an Open button in the Play Store UI on my app's product page. I have noticed that tapping on this Open button consistently selects one of my launchable Activities, but I wonder how does it choose which of my Activities to launch?

My guess is that it chooses the topmost one listed in the compiled manifest binary. I could test this with trial-and-error but it would take a while as there is an ingestion delay when publishing an app to the Play Store.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, your guess is right, the Play Store launch the first activity that has this intent filter in the `AndroidManifest.xml`:

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
</intent-filter>
```

If you already have your app published in the Play Store you can test all the combination you want without pushing every update:

- Change `AndroidManifest.xml`
- Build your app
- Install in your device
- Open the Play Store
- Search your app
- Press open